# Rename a Windows User account using Ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, user-accounts

I am new to Ansible. I have a requirement wherein I need to rename the 'Administrator' user account in a Windows host to something else, say 'NewUser' using Ansible.

Any suggestions on how I can rename a Windows user account using Ansible?

Thanks.

PS:-

I have tried searching for various Ansible modules to help me on this. However I could only find modules for adding a new user account, or changing the user password.

Comment: Not an answer, but renaming the administrator account is a classic example of weak security through obscurity. The account should preferably be disabled and not used at all in favor of user or application-specific, auditable accounts with membership in the administrators group and, disabled or not, it should be given a strong password. Renaming the account on top of that adds no real security, since it has a well-known SID and any malware that isn't completely imbecilic can use that to look it up (and malware that *is* completely imbecilic should be thwarted by your strong password).

Comment: Hello @Jeroen , Thanks for the reply and your suggestions. Administrator accounts are usually disabled in all our machines. This one came up as a specific requirement for some testing. Anyway, I found out a way to achieve this using Ansible. We just have to use a one line PowerShell script using 'win_shell' module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way to achieve this. Its pretty simple. Here is the playbook code:-

```
---

- name: Change Admin Username
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Change Admin Username
    win_shell: Rename-LocalUser -Name "Administrator" -NewName "NewUser"
```

Thanks.